# Calculated query on multivalued fields in access

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2010

I have a table 'Contacts' which has a multivalued field 'Department'. I have another table 'Outreach' and it has a field 'partner org'. I have a query which combines 'Contacts.Department' and 'outreach.[partner org]' into one field joining the two tables using an outer join on fullname field which is common in both tables. 
The SQL statement I have to combine the two fields is

```
Contacts.Department & ";" & Outreach.[Partner Org] AS [Dept/Partner Org]
```

If I run this query, I get the error saying

```
The multivalued field 'Contacts.Department' is not valid in the expression 'Contacts.Department & " " & Outreach.[Partner Org] AS [Dept/Partner Org]'
```

If I add the '.Value' to the multivalued field, I get multiple rows.

```
Contacts.Department.Value & " " & Outreach.[Partner Org] AS [Dept/Partner Org]
```

I want the output to have the multivalued valued field contents followed by a ';' and the partner org name all in the same cell.

Please can someone tell me to how to get this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up against a similar problem with these useful (from the end-users perspective) but irritating (from the perspective of those analysing) fields.

I came up with a workaround, using a form, that I think solves your problem. I added a pseudo-departments text field to the table, applied slightly modified code from [the fourth post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/485781-combine-fields-multiple-records-into-one-long-string.html) to the relevant field(s) "AfterUpdate" events as & when they change (I pass the current record & the SQL string only summarises that record).

```
Dim db As Database, _
rst As Recordset, _
strSQL As String

Me.Refresh

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "Select PseudoDepartment from YOURTABLE where UNIQUEIDNO = " & Me.UNIQUEIDNO & ";"
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

With rst
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
        .MoveFirst
        .Edit
        !PseudoDepartment = MakeList(Me.UNIQUEIDNO)
        .Update
    End If
End With
```

To initialise the pseudo-departments field, one could loop through all records one by one to generate the contents. One can then query the data normally and get the results in the form you indicated.

HTH.